# Statement of Purpose conventions in Canada and Europe

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, europe, canada

I'm applying to universities in Canada and Europe (The Netherlands, Belgium and France) for admission to their computer science/mathematics master's programmes.

I showed my statement of purpose to a professor in a European university who I've worked with in the past - they said that while my statement of purpose would work well in the European context I may have to advertise myself more aggresively to the Canadian universities I am applying to. They did however clarify that they aren't familiar with the Canadian system and were speaking from the experience they had with the US system.

1. Is there a difference between the expectations that Canadian universities have of an applicant's statement of purpose compared to those of European universities?
2. Would I be at a disadvantage if I were to submit a statement of purpose written to the standards of a European university to a Canadian university?

---

If the answers to the above questions are in the affirmative, I would be grateful for an example highlighting this "aggresiveness". Here is what I understand it to mean presently:
European: My thesis in X has prepared me for Y research.
Canadian: I am the ideal candidate for Y research since my thesis was on X.
My objection to the above explanation is that the Canadian method seems redundant; naturally, applicants would only write good things in their statements of purpose.

3. Does my objection highlight an invalidity in my present understanding of "aggresiveness" or does it simply stem from a poor understanding of Canadian expectations and culture?

Comment: The CV details "what you did" whether awesome or not. But the SoP is about the future, not the past. What are your goals and how do you intent to meet them? Mention the past only to support the future. Don't just recapitulate the CV.

Comment: @Buffy, I've been careful to do as you say here. However, what I'm concerned about is the general tone of my SoP. My SoP presently recounts my previous achievements (to support my goals, as you say) in a matter of factly manner. Would the Canadian universities take the lack of strong adjectives to mean that something is amiss? Would the lack of strong adjectives in my SoP make me appear weaker in comparison to a Canadian applicant who would (supposedly) use stronger adjectives than me?

Comment: @Buffy, what I'm asking here is: Would the Canadian admissions committees expect me to "blow my own trumpet"? I've updated the examples to highlight what I mean.

Comment: Praise should come from others, not yourself. And again, the _purpose_ of the SOP is **NOT** to "recount previous achievements". It is about where you are going, not where you have been.